# Need to filter the array based on checkbox value in React Native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, filtering

Basically, I have a Modal which consists of multiple check Boxes when I check them the value can easily enter into an array named: `checkedValues` and that array will be set to a state named: `setNewArray` and based on the values in `setNewArray` flatlist is showing but now I want that if a user unchecked the check box that particular unchecked value should be removed from `checkedValues` array and the `setNewArray` should be updated and then the flatlist show the result accordingly:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
} from 'react-native';

import {Search} from 'react-native-feather';

import SearchItem from './src/Screens/SearchItem';

import {getHeight, getWidth} from './src/Components/CommonFunctions';

//import {Modal} from 'react-native/Libraries/Modal/Modal';
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';

import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
import {
  widthPercentageToDP as wp,
  heightPercentageToDP as hp,
} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';

var checkedValues: any = [];

const FullfillmentScreen = ({route}) => {
  const {data} = route.params;
  const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState<string>('');

  useEffect(() => {
    var date = new Date().getDate();
    var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();
    var hour = new Date().getHours();
    var min = new Date().getMinutes();
    setCurrentDate(date + ' ' + month + ' ' + year + ', ' + hour + ':' + min);
  }, []);
  //   console.log(data);
  const array: any = [
    {
      id: '1',
      state: 'Created',
      date: 'Over Due',
      // image: require('../Assets/fonts/chegg.png'),
      packageNumber: 'PKGX-128788868-17HJGJG',
      name: 'muqsit Chowhan',
      delivery: 'Next Day',
      val: 'VAS',
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      state: 'Created',
      date: [currentDate],

      packageNumber: 'PKGX-128788868-17HJGJG',
      name: 'Ali',
      delivery: 'Next Day',
      val: 'VAS',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      state: 'Processing',
      date: [currentDate],
      // image: require('../Assets/fonts/chegg.png'),
      packageNumber: 'PKGX-128788868-17HJGJG',
      name: 'Chowhan',
      delivery: 'Next Day',
      val: 'VAS',
    },
    {
      id: '4',
      state: 'Picked',
      date: [currentDate],
      // image: require('../Assets/fonts/chegg.png'),
      packageNumber: 'PKGX-128788868-17HJGJG',
      name: 'Jamie',
      delivery: 'Next Day',
      val: 'VAS',
    },
    {
      id: '5',
      state: 'Packed',
      date: [currentDate],
      // image: require('../Assets/fonts/chegg.png'),
      packageNumber: 'PKGX-128788868-17HJGJG',
      name: 'qasim',
      delivery: 'Next Day',
      val: 'VAS',
    },
    {
      id: '6',
      state: 'Created',
      date: [currentDate],
      // image: require('../Assets/fonts/chegg.png'),
      packageNumber: 'PKGX-128788868-17HJGJG',
      name: 'abdullah',
      delivery: 'Next Day',
      val: 'VAS',
    },
    {
      id: '7',
      state: 'Created',
      date: [currentDate],
      // image: require('../Assets/fonts/chegg.png'),
      packageNumber: 'PKGX-128788868-17HJGJG',
      name: 'kamran',
      delivery: 'Next Day',
      val: 'VAS',
    },
    {
      id: '8',
      state: 'Created',
      date: [currentDate],
      // image: require('../Assets/fonts/chegg.png'),
      packageNumber: 'PKGX-128788868-17HJGJG',
      name: 'hamza',
      delivery: 'Next Day',
      val: 'VAS',
    },
  ];
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [apply, setApply] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [modalVisibile, setModalVisibile] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [new_Array, setNewArray] = useState<string>([]);
  // const [isCreated, setIsCreated] = useState<any>(false);
  // const [isProcessing, setIsProcessing] = useState<any>(false);
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState<any>({
    created: false,
    processing: false,
    picked: false,
    packed: false,
    completed: false,
    cancelled: false,
  });
  //const[isPicked,setIsPicked]=useState(false)

  const options = [
    'Created',
    'processing',
    'Picked',
    'Packed',
    'Completed',
    'Cancelled',
  ];
  console.log('=====================NEW VALUES=====================');

***************************MAIN LOGIC IMPLEMENTATION(Incorrect)**************************************

  const filtered = (type: any) => {
    if (isChecked.created === false) {
      //var newCheckedValues = checkedValues.replace('Created', ' ');
      //checkedValues = newCheckedValues;
      var newCheckedValues = checkedValues.filter(
        (item: any) => item !== 'Created',
      );
      console.log('newCheckedValues======>', newCheckedValues);
      setNewArray(newCheckedValues);
    }
    checkedValues.push(type);
    console.log('Checked Values Array====>', checkedValues);
    //console.log('Array========>', array);
    setNewArray(
      array.filter((item: any) => {
        return checkedValues.includes(item.state);
      }),
    );

  
  };
******************************************************************************************

***************************MAIN LOGIC IMPLEMENTATION(Correct)**************************************
 const filtered = (type: any) => {
    if (checkedValues?.includes(type)) {
      checkedValues = checkedValues.filter((item: any) => item !== type);
      setNewArray(checkedValues);
    } else {
      checkedValues.push(type);
      console.log('Didnot entered in if');
    }
    setNewArray(
      array.filter((item: any) => {
        return checkedValues.includes(item.state);
      }),
    );
    
  };
******************************************************************************************

 
  console.log('NewArray State======>', new_Array);

  console.log('Is Checked StateValue========>', isChecked);
return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, height: '100%'}}>
      <View style={styles.main}>
        <View style={styles.orgNameView}>
          <Text style={styles.orgData}>{data}</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.fullfillmentText}>Fulfillments</Text>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => setModalVisibile(true)}
          style={styles.filterView}>
          <Image
            source={require('./src/Assets/fonts/levels.png')}
            style={styles.filterIcon}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.textInput}>
          <Search size={30} color="#808080" style={styles.search} />
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Type to Search"
            value={search}
            onChangeText={query => setSearch(query)}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={{height: '80%'}}>
        <SearchItem
          data={array}
          search={search}
          setSearch={setSearch}
          isChecked={isChecked}
          data2={new_Array}
          setApply={setApply}
        />
      </View>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <Modal isVisible={modalVisibile} style={styles.modal}>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setModalVisibile(false)}>
            <View style={styles.modalView}>
              <View
                style={{
                  justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  // borderWidth: 1,
                  // borderColor: 'black',
                  paddingVertical: 5,
                }}>
                <Text style={styles.topBar} />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.filterHeadingView}>
                <Text style={styles.filterText}>Filters</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => {
                    //setIsCreated(false);
                    setNewArray([]);
                    //setIsProcessing(false);
                    setIsChecked(false);
                    checkedValues = [];
                    console.log(
                      'Checked Value Array after clear:===>',
                      checkedValues,
                    );
                  }}>
                  <Text style={styles.clearText}>Clear</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.statusView}>
                <Text style={styles.statusText}>Status</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.checkboxView}>
                <Text style={styles.checkItems}>{options[0]}</Text>
                <CheckBox
                  style={styles.checkbox}
                  disabled={false}
                  value={isChecked.created}
                  onValueChange={newValue => {
                    setIsChecked({...isChecked, created: newValue});
                    filtered('Created');
                  }}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.checkboxView}>
                <Text style={styles.checkItems}>{options[1]}</Text>
                <CheckBox
                  style={styles.checkbox}
                  disabled={false}
                  value={isChecked.processing}
                  onValueChange={newValue => {
                    setIsChecked({...isChecked, processing: newValue});
                    filtered('Processing');
                  }}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.checkboxView}>
                <Text style={styles.checkItems}>{options[2]}</Text>
                <CheckBox
                  style={styles.checkbox}
                  disabled={false}
                  value={isChecked.picked}
                  onValueChange={newValue => {
                    setIsChecked({...isChecked, picked: newValue});
                    filtered('Picked');
                  }}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.checkboxView}>
                <Text style={styles.checkItems}>{options[3]}</Text>
                <CheckBox
                  style={styles.checkbox}
                  disabled={false}
                  value={isChecked.packed}
                  onValueChange={newValue => {
                    setIsChecked({...isChecked, packed: newValue});
                    filtered('Packed');
                  }}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.checkboxView}>
                <Text style={styles.checkItems}>{options[4]}</Text>
                <CheckBox
                  style={styles.checkbox}
                  disabled={false}
                  value={isChecked.completed}
                  onValueChange={newValue =>
                    setIsChecked({...isChecked, completed: newValue})
                  }
                />
              </View>
              <View style={{flex: 1, height: getHeight(100)}}>
                <View style={styles.checkboxView}>
                  <Text style={styles.checkItems}>{options[5]}</Text>
                  <CheckBox
                    style={styles.checkbox}
                    disabled={false}
                    value={isChecked.cancelled}
                    onValueChange={newValue =>
                      setIsChecked({...isChecked, cancelled: newValue})
                    }
                  />
                </View>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.applyButtonView}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.buttonApply}
                  onPress={() => {
                    setModalVisibile(false);
                    setApply(true);
                  }}>
                  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Apply</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </Modal>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

I tried the filter method based on the boolean value of checkboxes. Although the console values are still good but either you check the value or uncheck it will be added to the `checkedValues` array.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the snippet you provide you can use the below code

```
const updateSelectedItems = selected => {
    const checkedValues = new_Array ?? [];

    const exist = _.findIndex(checkedValues, item => item === selected);

    if (exist > -1) {
      //exist in checkedValues remove from both arrays
      checkedValues.splice(exist, 1);
    } else {
      checkedValues.push(selected);
    }
    setNewArray([...checkedValues]);
  };
```

here 'selected' is used as a string if you need an object then you can change it to your requirements

let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thankyou for your help I came up with solution rather checking boolean value we need to checked the string present in checkedValues array and filter accordingly.